# Finding largest Number in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the largest number in the list using Python but I am getting an index out of range error. Can anybody help ?

```
numbers = [12, 33, 44, 55, 11, 19, 98, 17, 12]
largest = 0
for index in numbers:
    if largest < numbers[index]:
        largest = numbers[index]
print(largest)
```

Comment: So why didn't you want to use: `print(max(numbers))`?

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate a list using `for i in lst` the `i` is the **value** not the **index**, so in your case, it will be like below example. BTW: I guess you need to learn some basics of python list iteration.
**See**: https://favtutor.com/blogs/python-iterate-through-list.

**Note:** I just edited the `largest` variable using `numbers[0]` otherwise your program will not able to find the max value when you have **negative** values in the list.

```
numbers = [12, 33, 44, 55, 11, 19, 98, 17, 12] 
largest = numbers[0]   # take first element as max    
for value in numbers: 
    if largest < value: 
        largest = value
print(largest)
```

**OR** with single line python `max()`

```
largest = max(numbers)
```

**Working Code:** https://rextester.com/CLBM63548

Answer (score 0):

you can use `max(numbers)` to find the maximum number